# Hibernate's Transformers.aliasToBean() method

Tags: java, hibernate

```
 Query query =  getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
                 "select proj_employee.employee_no as employeeNo, ...
 .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));
```

Inside User.class
does the property employeNo need to be in capital letter?

```
private String EMPLOYEENO; 
//get/set for EMPLOYEENO
```

If I change the `EMPLOYEENO` to *small letter*, it doesn't work. Can anyone explain why the variable name must be all capital letters?

Comment: Just a hunch, but what's your back-end DBMS?

Comment: @Stefan oracle. but i dont think it related to backend dbms

Comment: Only Oracle forces all-caps table names, I think. I'm unsure if that causes the issue which you're seeing, or if it's cross-dbms.

Comment: @Stefan It doesn't matter if this is oracle specific or not. If you want your code to be portable, use `addScalar`.

Comment: Sure, but if this IS the issue, it's portability as a result for putting in Oracle hacks. This wouldn't be the first time this happened, either. The limit of 30 characters to a column name is prime example of another Oracle "gotchya" when using ORMs.

Comment: Is there anyway to fix this case mismatch with annotation like @Column in our DTO? In my case SQL query which has to be run is out of my hand to change the aliases, So I had to define all the setter and properties in UPPERCASE which is not good looking, Can I define them in standard camel case way and use annotation on them? and will this hibernate transformer will read those annotation?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See the [Hibernate 3.2: Transformers for HQL and SQL](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/) blog post:

> #### SQL Transformers
>
> With native sql returning non-entity
>   beans or Map's is often more useful
>   instead of basic `Object[]`. With
>   result transformers that is now
>   possible.
>
> ```
> List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createSQLQuery(
>   "SELECT st.name as studentName, co.description as courseDescription " +
>   "FROM Enrolment e " +
>   "INNER JOIN Student st on e.studentId=st.studentId " +
>   "INNER JOIN Course co on e.courseCode=co.courseCode")
>   .addScalar("studentName")
>   .addScalar("courseDescription")
>   .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentDTO.class))
>   .list();
>
> StudentDTO dto =(StudentDTO) resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
> ```
>
> Tip: the `addScalar()` calls were
>   required on HSQLDB to make it match a
>   property name since it returns column
>   names in all uppercase (e.g.
>   "STUDENTNAME"). This could also be
>   solved with a custom transformer that
>   search the property names instead of
>   using exact match - maybe we should
>   provide a `fuzzyAliasToBean()` method
>   ;)

Maybe you are facing the same situation than the one described in the tip in which case you should try to add calls to `addScalar()`.

Comment: Does it return column names in all uppercase for all DBMS's, or just Oracle?

Comment: @Stefan Not all DBMS I think but not only Oracle (as mentioned above, HSQLDB also do so). So at the end, it depends and the best practice is to use `addScalar` if you want to guarantee portability.

Answer (score 13):

Consider putting column aliases in double quotes. 
Oracle doesn't uppercase aliases specified in double quotes.

```
Query query =  getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
                 "select proj_employee.employee_no \"employeeNo\", ...
 .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class))
```

;