# How to transform SQL query in DTO with nullable properties?

Tags: nhibernate

Having a DTO like this:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{
     public int Id{get; set;}
     public int? Reference {get; set;}
}
```

How can I get it from

```
var q =_session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT Id, Reference FROM customers")
```

If I use

```
q.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<CustomerDTO>)
```

I get the following exception:

> NHibernate.PropertyAccessException : The type System.Int32 can not be
>   assigned to a property of type System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] setter
>   of Customer.Reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var customers = _session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT Id, Reference FROM customers")
    .AddScalar("Id", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
    .AddScalar("Reference", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<CustomerDTO>())
    .List<CustomerDTO>();
```

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445092/hibernate-aliastobean).

Comment: Adds the metadata to tell to nhibernate the projections types.

Comment: Very nice solution, question is, if the Nullable type was there for a reason... ;)

Comment: May be because the field Reference is null in the database.

Answer (score 1):

We had to map a nullable enum and were getting:

```
Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[ExampleEnumType]'.
```

The fix was to use:

```
.AddScalar("EnumTypeSqlAlias", NHibernateUtil.Enum(typeof(ExampleEnumType)))
```